# What does exactly mean "the spectral algebra $W_{A}$"?

Tags: logic, category-theory, propositional-calculus, quantum-mechanics, topos-theory

I'm trying to study an introduction to topos quantum theory but I keep finding this concept that I don't understand fully. In "A Topos Perspective on the Kochen-Specker Theorem:
I. Quantum States as Generalized Valuations" by Isham e Butterfield it's called "spectral algebra $W_{A}$, where $A$ is a bounded operator with discrete spectra, some boolean algebra obtained from the set of projectors that are in the spectral decomposition of $A$.
Tell me if you know something about that, please.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! You might want to give us a link to the original text so that we can read the original wording for ourselves, which would greatly help with figuring out the context of the question. Or you could embed the text itself in your question. You will find a lot more detail about how to write a good question [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: See [Spectral theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory) and the link with  John von Neumann, [The mathematical foundations of quantum mechanics (1932)](https://books.google.it/books?id=JLyCo3RO4qUC)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. This is the link https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9803055.pdf of paper which I've cited.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you would like to know about $W_A$?

Comment: I'd like to know better how this boolean algebra is defined